# Android - get lat long of two continuously moving objects

Tags: android, iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I want to create a Map with 2 Annotation(**A** and **B**) which would be moving continuously.

The lat-long of **A** would be coming from the server and the Lat-long of **B** would be device's lat-long.

I would also like to show a Line path between those 2 continuously moving objects(just as it shows on google map)

Here is the video link that demonstrate on what I need to do.
[**VIDEO**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UstY3gV8A1A)

The issue with me is how to capture the lat-long of A from the server because again the position of A is not fixed and A would be moving randomly.

Simple example would be A and B are 2 Moving objects and  We need to show the position of A on Device B.

Comment: Why do you have both iOS and Android tags?  Pick one. Be more specific about what your exact question is with some code you've tried.  Right now, the question is too broad.

Comment: Both Tags because this is to be implemented on Both Android and IOS.
**Regarding Question :** In simple words, I need to capture the Position of Device A on Device B real time. I haven't tried any code and just working on the feasibility of the requirement that I have.